# How to call a function from Textchange event in typescript/nativescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to call a function to update a variable based on TextField input.

I may be missing something in the documents, but I can't figure this out.

This is my XML

```
    <StackLayout class="p-20">
    <Label text="{{_message}}" class="h2 text-center" textWrap="true" />
    <TextField text="target" hint="Target" textChange="updateTarget" />
    
</StackLayout>
```

This is the main-view-model.ts

```
  updateTarget(_target: string) {
      console.log("Updating target: ${this._target}")
      this.message = `Target: ${this._target}`
    }
```

The updateTarget function isn't being called at all, I've tried extensive googling, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <TextField text="target" hint="Target" textChange="{{updateTarget}}" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

<TextField text="target" hint="Target" (change)="function ()" />